# Ember Cannot find template

Tags: ember.js

I've built a test app with ember-app-kit. I want to add a new route "analysis" but i get an error when i try to load it.

this is the main app file

```
var Exe = window.Exe = Ember.Application.create();
```

This is the route file

```
Exe.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({

});

Exe.AnalysisRoute = Ember.Route.extend({

});
```

this is the map file

```
Exe.Router.map(function () {
  this.resource('analysis');
});
```

and I've also 3 file, application.hbs, index.hbs, and analysis.hbs, in order:
application

```
<div>
    <div class="container" id="main">
        <div class="row">
            <div>
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    {{outlet}}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

index

```
<div>
    <button type="button">{{#link-to 'analysis'}} Analysis {{/link-to}}</button>
</div>
```

analysis

```
<div>
    <h1 class="bs-docs-featurette-title">Analysis</h1>
</div>
```

When i lunch grunt and i go to localhost:9000/analysis i see a 404

```
Cannot GET /analysis
```

or if i click on the button link doesn't seems to do anything.
I've checked the app with ember-inspector and the view doesn't appear.

EDIT: I've found the solution

```
<div>
    {{#link-to 'analysis'}}<button type="button">Analysis</button>{{/link-to}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not about being able to find the template. Ember is trying to get the model for analysis by making an AJAX call. This fails, and the error stops the transition. To turn this behavior off, implement a null `model` hook in `AnalysisRoute`.

Comment: I have done it: `model: function() { return null; }` but doesn't work